# MySQL database setup for blog created by ghost CMS

Tags: content-management-system, ghost-blog

I'm new to Ghost CMS it uses SqlLite db by default and I am using Editorial theme for my blog/ website and I want use MySQL database for my blog/ website which is created by Ghost CMS 
I need step by step procedures to change SqlLite db to Mysql db

https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/ghost/configure-mysql-database

referred this link but I didn’t get How to setup DB

I need to create a blog/website using GhostCMS which has MySql db

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate your contents to MySQL,

1. Login to ghost dashboard.
2. Go to Settings -> Labs -> Migration options and click Export. This will export the contents of your blog.
3. Make a new installation of Ghost with **`ghost install`**.
4. Provide your MySQL connection credentials.
5. Login to the new installation of ghost and under Settings -> Labs -> Migration
   options, click **Import** and select the export file downloaded in
   step 2.

You may need to copy the **contents** (Contains images and other uploads) folder to the new installation.